# Custom marker for react native maps GeoJson

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I am showing some polygons and markers in react native maps using GeoJson. The GeoJson had a markerComponent property for showing marker but i want to conditionally check and show different markers. anyway to implement the same in react native maps GeoJson component? Every marker object contains some values and condition will be applied to decide which component as marker.

```
          <MapView
          ref={mapRef}
          // scrollEnabled={false}
          rotateEnabled={false}
          scrollDuringRotateOrZoomEnabled={false}
          loadingEnabled={true}
          provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} // remove if not using Google Maps
          style={styles.map}
          // minZoomLevel={19}
          // maxZoomLevel={19}
          options={{
            disableDefaultUI: true,
          }}
          initialRegion={initialRegion}>
          <Geojson
            markerComponent={<CarMarker height={40} width={80} />} // i want different markers based on value from marker object
            geojson={geoJsonDummy}
            strokeColor="red"
            fillColor="green"
            strokeWidth={2}
          />
```